# CSV Import: Simple Products not linked to Configurable Product

Tags: configurable-product, import, ce-1.9.1.0, csv, simple-product

I'm importing Configurable products using the `Import/Export` tool but can't get the simple products to be associated with the **configurable product**.

The CSV looks like this<sup>**1**</sup>.

```
_type,        _super_attribute_code, _super_products_sku, sku,     style,...
configurable, style,                 ,                    Conf1,   ,
simple,       ,                      Conf1,               Simple1, Style1
simple,       ,                      Conf1,               Simple2, Style1
```

**The 3 products are correctly created but not associated.**

Is this the correct way to use the _super columns? Is there something I've missed?

---

**1**: White-space is added for readability

Comment: I suggest you use your own custom import for complicated product types sur as grouped, configurable or bundle. Magento's profile import is not to be relied on, as it is just crap, let's face it.

Comment: I have to agree with Julien. Give Magmi a try.

Comment: Does it use the same CSV file format I've used here?

Comment: As suggested I used Magmi and it solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the order.
You need to add simple products first, then configurable products in excel.

```
_type,        _super_attribute_code, _super_products_sku, sku,     style,...
simple,       ,                      Conf1,               Simple1, Style1
simple,       ,                      Conf1,               Simple2, Style1
configurable, style,                 ,                    Conf1,   ,
```

Comment: When I do that I receive this error during the Import "Check Data": Product with specified super products SKU not found in rows: 1, 2

Comment: put _super_products_sku empty for simple ones and add as simple1,simple2 in _super_products_sku of configurable and check.

Comment: Setting _super_products_sku to "Simple1,Simple2" on the configurable product and blanking it out on the simple products gives: Product with specified super products SKU not found in rows: 3

Answer (score 0):

For importing the configurable product along with its associated (simple) products. In the product CSV you will have to add an extra attribute which are not mentioned in above comments. Also after exporting CSV magento will not add the attributes in CSV.

First create your CSV file with all data and then at the end of CSV file add these attributes:

- configurable_attributess
- simples_skus

**Uses of the attributes:**

- `configurable_attributes` : If you have size attribute then for all simple products add the Size in this attribute column and for configurable product add name size, like the screen shot below:
  [image]
- `simples_skus`: In the attribute column left all the simple product blank and for configurable product add all the simple sku's separated by comma. same as the screen shot below:
  [image]

Now when the CSV is uploaded the configurable product will get uploaded with its configurable options(color, size etc) and all the associated(simple) products will be added.

Hope it help someone! Cheers